# New to VBA: Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or operation-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a user-selected workbook into the active workbook, specifying the sheet and range on the source and on the destination. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2:M1000").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data - Previous day").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Close False
    
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
End Sub
```

I keep getting a "Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or operation-defined error" and I am not sure what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

TIA

Comment: can you step through and provide details which row the error occurs on?

Comment: The error comes from this line: OpenBook.Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2:M1000").Copy

Comment: try to split it into multiple statements to know where the error comes from ```dim wks as worksheet = OpenBook.Sheets("Raw Data")

dim rng as Range = wks.Range("A2:M1000")

rng.Copy

``` then step through those lines

Comment: error is in the: wks = OpenBook.Sheets("Raw Data") line

Comment: try to use OpenBook.Worksheets instead of Sheets

Comment: `"A2-M1000"` is not a valid range reference, or is the `-` in your question a typo? Also your question has `PasteSpecialxlPasteValues`.

Comment: I didn't even notice that range typo. Fixed it but doesn't solve the error :(

Comment: Fixed the question

Comment: Split into steps: `Dim ws As Worksheet`, `Set ws = OpenBook.Worksheets("Raw Data")`, `ThisWorkbook.Workseets("Raw Data - Previous day").Range("A2:M1000").Value = ws.Range("A2:M1000").Value`. Please report back on which of those lines throws an error and what the error message is.

Comment: *`Worksheets`....

Comment: The error you get occurs when VBA can't access an object that should be there. In the line in question there are 3 objects: the workbook, the worksheet and the range. @BigBen showed you how to separate them out so that you can know which one fails. A less obvious possibility is that the workbook doesn't have time to open. If that is the case your code would run when you step through it with F8 but not when you run it on F5, Either way, this is not a case of coding but of debugging and trouble shooting. Learn the techniques involved here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx?em_x=22

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I tried separating them and figured out where the error was. Your input was very helpful. I have posted the code that worked as the answer

Comment: Would you please explain what caused the error, them this question may be useful to the comunity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(3).Range("A2:M1000").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Close False
    
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    
End Sub
```